# npm start giving errors when start

Tags: reactjs

I am new to web development using react and I've been having problems using npm start with this error.i don't know if is a problem with dependencies in package.json
[problem in Starting the development server...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjT7p.png)

Comment: Need a little more information than that. Did you run `npm install` before running `npm start`?

Comment: yes i have, npm build and bug test too

Comment: Did you create your react app with create-react-app? As in, is the app configured properly to run? If you've got Node and npm installed, create-react-app is an out of the box starter solution.